# Coloring words in text bash

Tags: bash, text, colors, sed

im beginner with Linux. I have a problem with coloring word in text.

```
red="\033[31m"
green="\033[31m"
blue="\033[34m"
endColor="\033[0m"

line=$(echo -e $input | sed -e "s/${word}/\ ${red} \ ${word} \n \${endColor}/g")
echo $line
in the standard output is this instead of red colored "word"
>> sdngasf 033[31m word n ${endColor}sdaadmfuw
```

Can anyone help me with this problem, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should use $'\e...' instead of "\033"

```
input="hello stack overflow"
word=stack

red=$'\e[31m'
green=$'\e[31m'
blue=$'\e[34m'
endColor=$'\e[0m'

line=$(echo -e $input | sed -e "s/${word}/${red}${word}${endColor}/g")
echo $line
```

this will output "hello stack overflow" with red "stack".

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need the `-e` options to either `echo` or `sed`, but you definitely should write `"$input"` and `"$line"` unless your intention is to drop newlines, tabs and whitespace sequences, in case they are present.

Comment: @rici You need the `-e` option for `echo` to process the color escapes. Though the `sed` broke the original syntax anyway, so not really needed here. Simpler would be to just use bash string replacement with  `line="$(echo -e "${input//${word}/${red}${word}${endColor}}")"` and you can keep the color variables op had originally.

Comment: @BroSlow: I know why it was needed in the OP. But neither are needed here. Fwiw, a good answer would explain why that broke in sed, and why it's useful to quote `$line` and `$input`, but sadly, CBA.

Answer (score 0):

In many system today, you can use 256 colors in bash.
To see how to format the output, test this program:

```
cat color_test.sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# generates an 8 bit color table (256 colors) for reference,
# using the ANSI CSI+SGR \e[48;5;${val}m for background and
# \e[38;5;${val}m for text (see "ANSI Code" on Wikipedia)
#
echo -en "\n   +  "
for i in {0..35}; do
        printf "%2b " $i
done
printf "\n\n %3b  " 0
for i in {0..15}; do
echo -en "\e[48;5;${i}m  \e[m "
done

for i in {0..6}; do
        i=$((i*36 +16))
        printf "\n\n %3b  " $i
        for j in {0..35}; do
                val=$((i+j))
                echo -en "\e[48;5;${val}m  \e[m "
        done
done
echo -e "\n"
```

Comment: [code origin](http://bitmote.com/index.php?post/2012/11/19/Using-ANSI-Color-Codes-to-Colorize-Your-Bash-Prompt-on-Linux)